# Photo sharing from iOS photo app Xcode swift

Tags: ios, swift, sharing, photos, file-sharing

OK  - I need a genius expert.  I want my app to import pictures directly from the photos app using the share button.  My app can import pdfs using UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey no problems.  I have defined two document types: public.jpeg and public.image and enabled Privacy Photo Library Usage with $(PRODUCT_NAME) photo use.  When using the photo app share my app does not show up.  It does show up with photo share from other 3rd party apps.  I don't want this to be a photo app extension but rather import the photo directly from the photos app into my app.  I do see the dropbox app show up so I know it should be possible.  Using Xcode 8.3 - 10.3 Thanks!

Bob

Comment: Consider reworking your question. I use photos from the iOS Photos app all the time with no issues. If you could reformat your question, using markdown, telling us what you've tried, showing us some code, and making the *specific* issue a replicable one... maybe I or someone else here can help you. Thanks.

Comment: IOS now supports this through both activity and share extensions